# Get the multi-dimensional value of an object by variable

Tags: javascript

```
x = {'name': {'first': 'dean'}}
```

On the example above, I am aware that `x['name']['first']` will get the value `dean`. But can we assign `['name']['first']` into a variable? Something like:

```
x = {'name': {'first': 'dean'}}
y = ['name']['first']
x[y]  // this will output to dean
```

Comment: FYI: In JavaScript terms, there are no arrays in your code.

Comment: Specifically the lodash in your question did